# How to improve FPS performance in Gnome?

Tags: drivers, gnome, xorg, 17.04

**Problem:** Moving windows, accessing the Activities overlay etc. is jerky and not smooth.

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome (hey, [soon](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/04/ubuntu-unity-is-dead-desktop-will-switch-back-to-gnome-next-year/) I'll just be able to say Ubuntu!) on **17.04**. My hardware is a 4k screen with `Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)` running on `i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8` with 16GB RAM.

I don't think it should be jerky.

### What I've tried

I've tried uninstalling `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, as recommended on a [redit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/4jejxm/why_are_gnome_320_animations_slow_in_terms_of_lag/) (which refers to a [note on a Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/x11/xserver-xorg-video-intel) saying it's deprecated), although I could not find the `xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` referred to in that post. There was no noticeable difference.

I've tried running the **Wayland** session. (click your name in the gdm log in screen, use the cog icon to select Gnome on Wayland, then enter your password). If anything this is worse, although I have no way to measure this except my eyes.

Comment: Thanks, might try that although it doesn't list 17.04 as supported

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue till this morning. Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 is running Gnome 3.24, and this issue seem to affect every Gnome 3.2x versions.

> I've tried uninstalling xserver-xorg-video-intel, as recommended on a
>   redit post (which refers to a note on a Debian package saying it's
>   deprecated), although I could not find the xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
>   referred to in that post. There was no noticeable difference.

I saw the same "solution" on internet, that it seemed the only one around because distros with Gnome 3.20 or higher are not so much today.

I solved this opening "Software & Updates" (installed by default), went to the tab "Additional Drivers" and put the "Do not use this device" (before it was set on Intel-microcode), as in the screenshot:

[Change to "Do not use this device", instead of intel-microcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35UtR.png)

Restart shouldn't be needed, but I did it anyway and I suggest you to do the same.
Just that solved the issue for me.

After that I've also tried to change the GPU's driver, and saw little differences between them, but this is very hardware-related, I think. So try to tweak it and see what is more performing on your machine.

Comment: deactivating intel-microcode did not change anything for me

Comment: I don't have any additional drivers installed there (using Intel's on chip graphics), so nothing to disable...